# Why cout does not output the content of my vector<string>?

Tags: c++

I am trying to get to print the content of a `vector<string>` in a for loop. I have a class with a method that inserts values into a `vector<string>` and returns it. I then use a for loop to print the content.

**Here is the relevant code:**

```
class MyClass {
    vector<string> fizz_buzz (const int max) {
        vector<string> v1;
        const auto it = v1.begin();

        for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
            if (i % 5 == 0 && i % 3 == 0) {
                v1.insert(it, "FizzBuzz!");
            } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
                v1.insert(it, "Buzz");
            } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
                v1.insert(it, "Fizz");
            } else {
                v1.insert(it, to_string(i));
            }
        }
        return v1;
    }
};

int main() {
    // MyClass my_class;
    MyClass* ptr1 = nullptr;
    const auto v1 = ptr1->fizz_buzz(100);
    for (const string &s : v1) {
        cout << s << "\n";
    }
    delete ptr1;
    return 0;
}
```

**I expected to have this output:**

```
1
2
Fizz
4
Buzz
Fizz
...
```

**instead I have nothing.**

I suspect the problem to be that my pointer is null but then I don't know why exactly that is.

Comment: A null pointer doesn't point at a valid object. Calling a member function without a valid object means that the behavior of your program is undefined. Don't do that.

Comment: If you always answer the question "*To what valid object does my pointer point?*" before using the pointer, you will never have any further problems using pointers...

Comment: OP says - in a comment on the below answer - that he made the class just for a test

Comment: @Amit -- it's not needed for a minimal reproducible example. Especially when it's done wrong (`fizzbuzz` being private, for example).

Answer (score 4):

You are calling `fizz_buzz()` on an invalid `MyClass` object via a `nullptr` object pointer, which is *undefined behavior*.  You don't even need the object at all, since it doesn't hold any data that `fizz_buzz()` is using.

After fixing that, `fizz_buzz()` is `private`, so your `main()` can't call it.  You need to make it `public` instead.

After fixing that, you are calling `vector::begin()` on an empty `vector` (effectively returning the `vector::end()` iterator) and saving it in the `it` variable, but you are not updating `it` every time you call `vector::insert()`. The inserts are invalidating `it`, but you are not accounting for that. To insert at the back of the `vector`, you need to call `vector::end()` fresh each time, or just use `vector::push_back()` instead.

Try this:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    static vector<string> fizz_buzz (const int max) {
        vector<string> v1;

        for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
            if (i % 5 == 0 && i % 3 == 0) {
                v1.push_back("FizzBuzz!");
            } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
                v1.push_back("Buzz");
            } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
                v1.push_back("Fizz");
            } else {
                v1.push_back(to_string(i));
            }
        }
        return v1;
    }
};

int main() {
    const auto v1 = MyClass::fizz_buzz(100);
    for (const string &s : v1) {
        cout << s << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/VnVIrk)

Answer (score 0):

First problem: `fizz_buzz` is a private member of the class and so your program won't compile. Second problem: you're trying to dereference a `nullptr` to call `fizz_buzz`, so even if we fix the privacy issue, your code has undefined behaviour. On my system it segfaults.

You don't need the class because the class does not manage any state that the `fizz_buzz` function needs access to. Get rid of it. Just write a function `fizz_buzz`. Then use `push_back` with your vector rather than trying to insert at the beginning.

```
vector<string> fizz_buzz(const int max) {
    vector<string> v1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
        if (i % 5 == 0 && i % 3 == 0) {
            v1.push_back("FizzBuzz!");
        } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
            v1.push_back("Buzz");
        } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
            v1.push_back("Fizz");
        } else {
            v1.push_back(to_string(i));
        }
    }

    return v1;
}
```

And in `main`:

```
int main() {
    const auto v1 = fizz_buzz(100);

    for (const string &s : v1) {
        cout << s << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The program does compile. I know I don't need the class but I'm learning cpp and this is a test...

Comment: @YounesMdarhriAlaoui the program you have shown does not compile, because 1) it is missing required `#include`'s (which I assume you have and just omitted here); and 2) `fizz_buzz()` is implicitly `private`, thus `main()` cannot access it. When posting code to StackOverflow, make sure it is a proper [mcve].

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes I've omitted some parts of the program (obviously) and the method by default uses the public modifier... if it wasn't the case, the program would not compile and it does. The problem was in the insert

Comment: Side note: Proper instruction in C++ will teach when to and when not to use classes. In general, when a class has no state (no member variables) question whether or not it should be a class and I've found it better to put the onus on proving why it should be a class rather than proving why it should not be a class. A `namespace` may be  a better option